# Wrapping mat-form-field into component - mat-error validation wont show on submit

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

**My goal**: to create a custom components based on composition on angular material components

**Problem**: wrapping mat-form-field and mat-error into components won't trigger the validation when user press the submit button on parent component.

I have create the demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysnmo2

---

And my question/notes are:

1. What is the correct way to achieve this? in demo there is a simple
       input + validation, but later there will be a lot  of more complex
       components
2. I have try to implement the ControlValueAccessor but it won't work
   for me, or maybe I fail to implement this. I'm getting the error
   *Cannot set property validator of [object Object] which has only a getter* when I try to bind the ngControl to the formControl attribute, it is in the demo example in *cva-input*.
3. Beside that in #2, is the ControlValueAccessor designed for this type of components? I got the feeling that it was introduce to support simple input-like components, that will be placed inside mat-form-field and work with the other material components, it is not what I'm trying to do.
4. Found a trick that will trigger the validation, it invoke the *markAllAsTouched* method and next *updateValueAndValidity* on every formGroup control. But my biggest concern here is if I'm doing this in right way? And second how the forms validation works, and why its not working when it is wrapped in separate component?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this..

```
  constructor(
    @Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl,
  ) {
    if (this.ngControl != null) {
      // Setting the value accessor directly (instead of using the providers) to avoid running into a circular import.
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }
```

and then add this to you input `[formControl]="ngControl"`
then

```
  writeValue(val: string): void {
    this.ngControl.control?.setValue(val);
  }
```

Comment: when trying to bind `[formControl]="ngControl"` on input I get an error: 
'Property formControl is not provided by any applicable directives nor by input element'

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to abandon this idea, as it generate a lot of errors and unexpected behaviours even if you'll achieve it. I suggest you to do a directive or wrapper component where you'll pass mat-form-field as an ng-content.
So first idea - directive:

```
<mat-form-field directiveCustomizingField> ... </mat-form-field>
```

Second idea - wrapper component:

```
<custom-wrapper>
  <mat-form-field> ... </mat-form-field>
</custom-wrapper>
```

Don't underestimate power of directives as they can do much for you - add styles, generate some HTML etc.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain this more, is this against some material general concept? I have been looking for some guides, but so far didn't find any useful information about this approach